# Создание массива из чисел, делящихся на К

Tags: java

```
int k = 10;
int n = 4;
int a[] = new int[n];
for (int i = 20; i < a.length; i++) {
    for (i = 10; i < 100; i++) {
        if (a[i] % k == 0)
            System.out.println(a[i]);
}
```

Нужно создать массив, состоящий из элементов, которые делятся на число `K`. Допустим, `K` равно `10`.

Как это сделать? Надо ли *"открыть"* цикл тут или нет, чтобы код заработал?

Comment: int i = 20; i < a.length; i++

Comment: Вы пытаетесь взять 20й элемент массива, в котором 4 элемента

Comment: а вообще код ооочень странный)

Answer (score 6):

Для получения чисел, кратных `k`, достаточно перемножить `k` на числа от `1` до `n` (включительно) и сохранить результаты умножения в массив:

```
int k = 10;
int n = 4;
int[] result = new int[n];
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    result[i - 1] = k * i;
```

Или с использованием `IntStream`:

```
int k = 10;
int n = 4;
int[] result = IntStream.range(1, n + 1).map(e -> e * k).toArray();
```

---

Если результирующие числа должны начинаться с определённого числа `minNumber` (например, со `100`, то есть с трёхзначного), то можно заранее посчитать значение первого элемента (`firstNumber`):

```
int k = 10;
int n = 4;
int minNumber = 100;
int firstNumber = minNumber % k == 0 ? minNumber : minNumber + k - minNumber % k;
int[] result = new int[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    result[i] = firstNumber + k * i;
```

Comment: Но мне требует создать массив и элементы должны быть трехзначные числа

Comment: @HaykMkrtchyan массив и так создаётся (`int[] result`). Так всё-таки числа должны быть двузначные, как у вас было изначально в вопросе, или трёхзначные?

Comment: нет трехзначные, простите если ошибся... просто у меня дает ошибку java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: @HaykMkrtchyan добавил в ответ вариант с числами, начинающимися с `100`.